# Multiple Client write methods in I/O Multiplexing

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server, tcp

I want to write to multiple clients by checking only FD_SET 1 in FD_ISSET in the if statement, but I want to know how.  Currently, only a single client can write, but how can I write to multiple clients?

```
struct result
{
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    struct tm tm;
};
int main()
{
    //omit
    while(1)
    {
        allfds = readfds;
        printf("Select Wait %d\n", maxfd);
        fd_num = select(maxfd + 1 , &allfds, (fd_set*)0,  (fd_set *)0, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(listen_fd, &allfds))
        {
            addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);
            client_fd = accept(listen_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addrlen);
            k++;
            FD_SET(client_fd,&readfds);
            if (client_fd > maxfd)
                maxfd = client_fd;
            printf("Accept OK\n");
            printf("maxfd : %d\n",maxfd);
            continue;
        }
        for (i = 0; i <= maxfd; i++)
        {
            sockfd=i;
            if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &allfds))
            {
                printf("sockfd : %d\n",sockfd);
                memset(result.buf, 0x00, MAXLINE);
                if (read(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result)) <= 0)
                {
                    close(sockfd);
                    FD_CLR(sockfd, &readfds);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (strncmp(result.buf, "quit\n", 5) ==0)
                    {
                        close(sockfd);
                        FD_CLR(sockfd, &readfds);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_pointer = &result;
                        lt = &(result_pointer->tm);
                        result.buf[strlen(result.buf)-1]='\0';
                        printf("Read : %s %s",result.buf,asctime(lt));
                        for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
                        {
                        write(sockfd+j,&result,sizeof(result));
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            
                if (--fd_num <= 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used a for statement to execute write multiple times, but the value was not passed to all connected clients, and the buf value was also output strangely.

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<k;j++)` k is undefined

Comment: initialized to k = 0

Comment: Buffer the data, keep state information on whether or not you wrote it to a specific client, use that state and results of `select`/`poll`, etc. so you only write to those who are writable. Alternately use some existing library like libev/libuv, etc. to simplify your flow/handling.

Comment: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) should have the answer to your question, specifically the [section about `poll`](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/split/slightly-advanced-techniques.html#poll).